# How to recursively move all files (including hidden) in a subfolder into a parent folder in *nix?

Tags: command-line-interface, nix, mv, wildcards

This is a bit of an embarrassing question, but I have to admit that this late in my career I still have questions about the mv command.

I frequently have this problem: I need to move all files recursively up one level. Let's say I have folder foo, and a folder bar inside it. Bar has a mess of files and folders, including dot files and folders. How do I move everything in bar to the foo level?

If foo is empty, I simply move bar one level above, delete foo and rename bar into foo.  Part of the problem is that I can't figure out what mv's wildcard for "everything including dots" is. A part of this question is this - is there an in-depth discussion of the wildcards that cp  and mv commands use somewhere (googling this only brings very basic tutorials).

Answer (score 19):

In Bash (and some others), you can use brace expansion to accomplish this in one line:

```
mv bar/{,.}* .
```

The comma separates a null and a dot, so the `mv` command sees filenames that match `*` and `.*`

Comment: this attempts to move '..' too, fails with message 'resource is busy'. Works nonetheless.

Comment: Suggested by anonymous user: `To eliminate the error caused by also matching "." and "..", use this command:

mv bar/{,.[!.],..?}* .`

Answer (score 3):

This one harvests all files from subfolders and moves them to current dir

```
find . -type f -exec mv -iv \{} . \;
```

If You want to owerwrite files with same name, use

```
yes y | find . -type f -exec mv -iv \{} . \;
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is to do it in two command, because * doesn't match .whatever

```
cd /foo
mv bar/* ./
mv bar/.??* ./
```

You do not want to use bar/.* which I found out while committing this mistake:

```
rm -rf ./.*
```

This is a BAD THING. Anyone want to guess why? ;-)

Comment: I don't think Bash or Zsh expands `.*` to `.` and `..`. Zsh doesn't for me at least.

Comment: Mikael: I can promise that bash does (or at least did), as I had to recover user directories that I wiped out by doing just that

Answer (score 2):

First thing to know about globbing --it's done by the shell, not the command.  Check your shell's man page for all the details.

Answer (score 1):

`mv .??* *` will take care of anything except dot followed by a single character.  If that's common for your situation, you can add `.[a-zA-Z0-9]*`.  That will still leave files with names such as `.;`, `.^`, and `.^I` (tab).  If you need to handle everything, you'll need to be a bit more complex.

```
mv .. `ls -f | egrep -v '^.$|^..$'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a directory structure `/foo/bar/` and you want to move all files under `bar` one step above, go into the `bar` directory and type the following:

```
find . -depth -print0 | cpio --null -pvd ../
```

Generally, I think `cpio(1)` is better for these kind of tasks. You can check out the detailed documentation by issuing `info cpio` in your shell.